# Celery celery_taskmeta table for results backend not saving until task completed

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

My celery is using postgresql for a backend, but it seems that the celery_taskmeta table is only created and tasks saved to it only after they're completed, rather than being able to track which ones are in the various status states.

Is there some configuration issue for me that would cause that? Or does it only save the final result to the backend, rather than the status along the way.

Comment: It is called "result backend" for a reason, not "progress backend"... but i believe in celery multi runner you can see which tasks are currently executed

Answer (score 2):

Set [`task_track_started`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_track_started) to `True` in your celery config, this will add tasks to the result backend as soon as the task enters the `STARTED` state.